# Hide "All Records" for Role

Tags: security, acumatica, erp

The S130 says "The All Records tab shows all records without any filter applied. Once any filter is available for the form (whether it is created by the user or shared with the user), this tab appears automatically as the first tab."

How can I remove the All Records tab for a specific user/role?
The other ones are hide-able via making it "not shared."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally agree with @Mick: you cannot hide the **All Records** tab.

To Limit access to records in the **All Records** tab, you should define additional conditions for the generic inquiry screen, not data entry form:

[image]

As mentioned here: [How do you limit the Leads viewable to an owner, role, or workgroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384614/how-do-you-limit-the-leads-viewable-to-an-owner-role-or-workgroup/41399394#41399394) - to limit access to records in the data entry form, you should:

- either create a custom data entry screen with filter conditions for primary view and Lead ID selector identical to those defined for the associated inquiry or customize
- or customize primary view and Lead ID selector in the LeadMaint BLC extension to match conditions defined for the associated inquiry

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the All Records tab shows the unfiltered data of the form. If you restrict access to this tab, you won't access the form and any of its tabs at all. But if that's what you need, you can manage access to any screens on the Access Rights by Screen form (SM201020).

Comment: Its not possible for GI via that screen.

Comment: You can manage access right for only published GI screens that have been added to the site map and that you can open on the navigation pane. Thus, on the Access Rights by Screen form (SM201020) you can do it.  
If you replace an entry form with a generic inquiry, access rights to the generic inquiry are inherited from this entry form.

Comment: I think I explained unclearly.  
All tabs of the screen from your screenshot are filters except the All Records tab. This isn't a filter. This is the system tab that shows the entire unfiltered data of the screen. This tab shows the data that the screen would show with no filters (tabs). So you cannot restrict access to this tab, only to the whole screen.