# How do you limit the Leads viewable to an owner, role, or workgroup?

Tags: security, crm, acumatica, erp

After opening record from the GI, I am still able to page to the next record that is not within the GI's scope. How can I limit this to a specific workgroup, role, or owner?

The row-level access screens do not have anything for CRM there, owners nor workgroups seems to limit who can see what... there must be a way to limit the leads viewable for a salesperson... how is this done?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the Entry Point tab from the Generic Inquiry screen, you can match the selected inquiry to a data entry form. Once you have replaced the data entry form with this inquiry, when you try to click the name of the entry form in the navigation pane, you are redirected to the inquiry. If you select a record in the list, the data entry form opens and displays the details of the selected record. Also, if you create a new record from the inquiry, the entry form opens.

[image]

There is no mechanism to automatically match behavior of a data entry form with the associated inquiry. When you select a record in the inquiry list, the associated data entry form opens. The opened entry form is not aware of filter conditions set up for the inquiry. To limit access to records in the data entry form, you should create a custom data entry screen with filter conditions for primary view and Lead ID selector identical to those defined for the associated inquiry.

Comment: Would you be able to offer any other solution to limit the leads screen? There must be a way to limit the leads viewable for a particular sales representative.

Comment: @Ahmed, currently there is no built-in mechanism to limit access to records on the leads screen. You can change default behavior by modifying the Leads screen with Acumatica Customization Tools.